# SOA record obscurity

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

Why do SOA records use a '.' instead of an '@' for contact email addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line typically found in a BIND zone file might look something like this:

```
@ IN SOA ns1.mydomain.com. administrator.mydomain.com. (
```

Alowing `@` in the email address would make parsing unnecessarily difficult and error prone.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `@` is not a valid character for use in DNS names.